# Super + D Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have set  from to minimize all windows settings to super + d button.

Some time later this **Super + D** button does not works.

When I check the setting i see that it is disabled.

[image]

What should I do not to disable itself after a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 14.04, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does not seem to work (at least to reveal the Desktop).

I would rely on the same shortcut as the one defined in the Unity Compiz plugin:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

To enable <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> without the need of defining a shortcut, just activate the Desktop Launcher icon in System Settings → Appearance → Behavior:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering what could cause this?

Comment: @akikara: In order to use Super+D you need to activate the Desktop launcher icon, nothing more.

Comment: This answer was the one that worked for me, not the answer in the duplicate item. Perhaps these aren't duplicates after all, or this answer should be included on the linked question.